# What is the longest winning streak in tennis with a player not dropping a single game

Tags: tennis, trivia

Saw these past few days that in the Australian Open 2013 Sharapova went two matches without dropping a single game. I'm wondering if there is any official record on the longest streak of sets/matches a player played without dropping a single game.

Comment: [What is the record for most consecutive games won?](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=165570) at manstennisforums.

Comment: Wikipedia articla on [wiinning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#Tennis) lists this record:
Most consecutive game wins (men): 25 games - 1993 Sergi Bruguera,
However, no reference is given there. And no record for women's tennis is listed there.

Comment: Bill Tilden won 57 straight in 1925. Source: *A terrible Splendour,* p.128.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What better place to start looking than to find the one of the most dominant player in tennis ever - [Esther VERGEER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esther_Vergeer) 
:) 
I found this [link](http://www.itftennis.com/wheelchair/players/player/profile.aspx?playerid=55000204) and just did a quick scan (there could be longer ones I was hasty) and found from

> 2009 Invacare World Team Cup - Women's Event    27 Jul - 02 Aug 2010(I am guessing it's 2009 not 2010 possible typo by the web admin part)

to

> Mercedes Open  Utrecht, Netherlands  04 Aug - 09 Aug 2009

She went

> eleven sets (five and half matches) without dropping a single game.

Of course this was only a quick search not an official one. Lets see how long this stand :)

Comment: I'm sure Esther Vergeer, "the most dominant player in tennis ever," is merely an opinion (and not to say I disagree). Otherwise, good work with the research and let's see if anything else comes in.

Comment: If the field is limited to wheelchair women's singles then it's a pretty good opinion :)

Comment: @user1655072 She didn't loose a single match in more than 10 years. She retired this month, with 470 consecutive wins (see wiki page)

Comment: If Vergeer's matches meet the criteria then I'd say that's the answer for sure. I'm positive nobody in professional men's or women's tennis has gone 11 sets without losing a game. No way.

Comment: Quora: [Which athlete dominated his or her sport for several years?](http://www.quora.com/Which-athlete-dominated-his-or-her-sport-for-several-years?share=1)

Answer (score 5):

For questions like this, one possible approach is to make a community-wiki answer, where several users can contribute if they find some relevant records.

### Grand Slams - Men

- [Sergi Bruguera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergi_Bruguera) won his second round match at [1993 French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_2) 6-0, 6-0, 6-0. He won also his first round match in straight sets and he won the third set 6-0. From these results alone we can see that he won at least 25 consecutive games. (Four bagel sets in a row and the last game in the preceding set.) Bruguera went on to win the tournament.
- [Karel Nováček](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karel_Nov%C3%A1%C4%8Dek) won his second round game at [1987 French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1987_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles#Section_3) 6-0, 6-0, 6-0. He also won his first round match in the straight sets and he won the last set of that match 6-0. This means winning at least 25 games in a row.

### Grand Slams - Women

- [Maria Sharapova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Sharapova) won her first two matches at [2013 Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_Singles#Section_8) 6-0, 6-0. In the third round she won the first four games in the match against Venus Williams. (Sources: [1](http://www.flashscore.com/match/IDtLwqVS/#point-by-point;1).) Which makes it 28 consecutive games in total. (Australian Open was her first tournament in [2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Sharapova#2013:_Third_shoulder_injury). She lost her last match in [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Maria_Sharapova_tennis_season).) See also: [Once In A Lifetime For Sharapova](http://www.wtatennis.com/news/article/3042968/title/once-in-a-lifetime-for-sharapova) at WTA website; [Australian Open 2013: Maria Sharapova hands out heavy defeat to hapless Venus Williams](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/tennis/australianopen/9810462/Australian-Open-2013-Maria-Sharapova-hands-out-heavy-defeat-to-hapless-Venus-Williams.html) - The Telegraph.
- [Wendy Turnbull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendy_Turnbull) won 6-0, 6-0 in the first two rounds at [1985 French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1985_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_Singles#Section_3). She lost in the third round 3-6, 4-6 to Hana Mandlíková. This means at least 24 consecutive games and at most 27 consecutive games. (She lost her last match at the preceding tournament in Sydney. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1985_Virginia_Slims_World_Championship_Series#November).)

### Useful links

- Wikipedia article [Shortest tennis match records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_tennis_match_records) lists triple bagel games (double bagel for women) at Grand Slams. However, these lists may be incomplete.