# What is the record of a tennis consecutive games won?

Tags: trivia, tennis

Is there any official statistics that show who has won many consecutive games in a particular court? I can only find those relative to winning streak of sets.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean games on the same court - but possibly by different players, right? There is an older question about consecutive games by a single player: [What is the longest winning streak in tennis with a player not dropping a single game](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2115)

Comment: ok that is fine but what I want exactly is for one same match (court) in Men's singles ( I would appreciate if it is for the currents tennis players)